# How to transplant patches in svn

Tags: svn, git, merge, patch, transplant

I used to use git to port features between different branches, `rebase`, `rebase --onto`, `cherry-pick` are typical tools I used. But now I have to work with svn. I don't like to use svn's built in `merge` command, cause it will combine all the commits into one "merge commit", though with some history traceability after 1.5. Say if I have a range of commits from r100 to r110 in `branchA`, now I want to port this feature to `branchB` and `branchC` by replaying these commits one by one with the same commit comment (resolve any conflicts in between). Is there any automatic tool which can do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any automated tool to do this, but you could implement one along the same lines of `git rebase`.  All it does it make a temporary directory and use `git format-patch` to to extract the changes you want to rebase and then `git am` to apply them back to the target root.  If you type `locate git-rebase` on your system you can read it -- it's a shell script.  It's probably `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-rebase`.

The `svn` equivalent would use `svn diff` and `svn log` to save the original commit information followed by `patch` and `svn commit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use [`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). The awesome `git` history won't be in the central repo, but you'll have a much better time managing the work on your end.

Comment: The downside to merging in git-svn is that the svn `mergeinfo` does not know about your shenanigans and future merges go poorly (or more poorly -- `svn merge` has done some truly stupid stuff in my experience).

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually doing this, but my colleagues won't. I'm trying to find a solution for them :)

Comment: @Ben My way is never to use svn merge, always track stuff in git.